# How to get reference to the parent segue of the Navigation Controller?

Tags: swift, xcode

**Hi,**

I'm actually working on an app with a storyboard of configuration, so I need to use an **Navigation Controller**. But before it I have a **View Controller** called **A** with a button witch segue to my **Navigation Controller**. In my case i want to get a reference to my **View Controller A** from a **View Controller** in my **Navigation Controller**. I tried to do this in the **View Controller** of my **Navigation Controller** to get reference to **View Controller A**:

```
ViewControllerA().myFunc
```

But that doesn't works. I know the reference is not good because I recreate a new instance of my ViewControllerA. Does someone have a good solution to reference my View Controller ?

[This is the representation in picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VILBr.png)

Also you can download my on Xcode project [Here](https://mega.nz/folder/tr52naTL#tf8gFMObNgsX0buVRXrOfw)

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define delegate protocole for viewControllerB and set viewControllerA as delegate for it

```
protocole ViewControllerBDelegate {
    func myFunc()
}

class ViewControllerB : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var myDelegate : ViewControllerBDelegate? // set the connection to viewControllerA in storyboard

    func someFunctionThatCallDelegate() {
        myDelegate?.myFunc() // Call the delegate which in your case will be viewControllerA
    }
...

class ViewControllerA : UIViewController, ViewControllerBDelegate {
    func myFunc() {
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier {
            if (identifier == "showingB") { // use identifier of segue set in storyboard
                if let vc = segue.destination as? ViewControllerB {
                    vc.delegate = self // set viewControllerA as delegate for viewControllerB
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I do this but I can't set viewControllerA as delegate for it because I segue to my Navigation Controller and no the ViewControllerB. How I can do ?

Comment: You can set viewControllerA as delegate of viewControllerB in the storyboard.

Comment: In the Connection Inspector, I cannot connect my View Controller A with my VC B, the "delegate" case does not appear.

Comment: You should see the delegate in the connection inspector of viewControllerB

Comment: Do not forget to set the class for viewControllerB and viewControllerA in storyboard

Comment: Ok thanks now i see 'MyDelegate' in the outlet of my ViewControllerB but i can't connect to others vc besides my ViewControllerB.

Comment: If you have added protocole to ViewControllerA in swift you should be able connect myDelegate to it in storyboard . ViewControllerA class must also be set in storyboard.

Comment: So sorry for the late reply, i see 'myDelegate' in the VC B but I can't drag the point to the VC A. I don't know in which file to put the protocol. Does it matter? In your code in the VC A there was not the 'func' before 'myFunc()' is this normal? Thanks

Comment: I forgot the func in VCA , I made the correction. VCA must implement the protocole for VCB. That why it is defined with : UIViewControllee,(parent class) ViewControllerBDelegate(implementing protocole for VCB)